# Does it make sense to use the KL-divergence between joint distributions of synthetic and real data, as a evaluation metric?

Tags: probability-distributions, information-theory, data-analysis

The KL-divergence is defined as: $D_{KL}(p(x_1)∥q(x_1))=\sum p(x_1)\, \log \Big( \dfrac{p(x_1)}{q(x_1)} \Big)$

I consider the Kullback-Leibler (KL) divergence as a performance metric for data synthesis.

Several studies used the KL divergence as a performance metric by computing over a pair of the real and synthetic marginal probability distribution for a given variable.

However, the joint distributions of variables in the synthetic and real data are also important for data synthesis.

**If the real and synthetic data have variables of $x_1$ and $x_2$, does it makes sense to measure the KL-divergence between $P_{synthetic}(x_1,x_2)$ and $P_{real}(x_1,x_2)$ to evalaute the similarity between two datasets?**

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: "Making sense" means whether using KL in this problem is (practically?) reasonable or appropriate for the research, based on the concept of KL divergence. Could this be the answer?

Comment: Can you describe clearly what you mean by data synthesis? What is the goal (without reference to any loss functions etc). What do you get, and what do you want to produce?

Comment: Data synthesis is synthesizing the data using a Generative model (e.g., Variational autoencoder (VAE), Generative adversarial networks (GAN)), by estimating the joint probability distribution of the real data. Using the trained generative model, we can generate(synthesize or simulate) the synthetic data mimicking the real data. In the case of GAN, model training is conducted until the classification model in GAN cannot differentiate between the real and synthetic data. Therefore, I want to evaluate the similarity of joint distribution between synthetic and real data.

Comment: So is you question if, when you have laws on two variables, you should consider the distance between the joint laws and not the marginal laws? The answer is trivially yes. This is already what folks do in things like GANs/VAEs (e.g., you can think of a distribution on images as a joint distribution of all the pixels of the images). Also, in synthesis objectives such as the Wasserstein distance, which incorporate the metric structure of the random variables, are generally preferred to KL.